# "unless indicated/noted/stated/... otherwise" or "unless otherwise indicated/noted/stated/..."?

Tags: usage

Which usage is more common or more natural?

> unless indicated otherwise

or

> unless otherwise indicated

*Why* is it more common?  Does it have to do with grammar, or simply convention?

Does the same preference hold when I substitute "indicated" with "stated", "noted", etc. ?

Comment: **unless otherwise Xed** is much more common, although [*unless indicated otherwise* has recently increased in popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unless+otherwise+indicated%2Cunless+indicated+otherwise&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunless%20otherwise%20indicated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunless%20indicated%20otherwise%3B%2Cc0).  I'm not sure why these are the way they are, though.

Answer (score 1):

As a native BrE speaker I would say that both were equally natural, grammatically correct, equally common and mean exactly the same thing.
The same applies for the other substitutions you ask about.